# Don't kwow how to retrieve properties from objects declared as abstract class type in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

I’m learning C# and I have a doubt about the use of inheritance in classes and I would like that somebody could help me.

If I have some classes that inherit from a abstract class, I can declare an object of the secondary class as of the type of the primary abstract class, like this:

```
Animal leopard = new Mammal();
```

Where `Mammal` is a class that inherit from the abstract class `Animal`. In this case, how can I access the properties that are exclusively from `Mammal` class? Look the following code for a better understanding:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal leopard = new Mammal("leopard", "mammal", "yellow", 80);
            Bird falcon = new Bird("falcon", "bird", "black", 300);
            Fish shark = new Fish("shark", "fish", "white", 80);
            List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();            

            animalList.Add(leopard);
            animalList.Add(falcon);
            animalList.Add(shark);

            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Class: {1}, Fur Collor: {2}, Running Speed: {3} km/h.",
                leopard.name, leopard.animalClass, leopard.furColor, leopard.runningSpeed);
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public abstract class Animal
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string animalClass { get; set; }
        }

        public class Mammal : Animal
        {
            public string furColor { get; set; }
            public double runningSpeed { get; set; }

            public Mammal(string name, string animalClass,
                string furColor, double runningSpeed)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.animalClass = animalClass;
                this.furColor = furColor;
                this.runningSpeed = runningSpeed;
            }
        }

        public class Bird : Animal
        {
            public string featherColor { get; set; }
            public double flightSpeed { get; set; }

            public Bird(string nam, string animalClass,
                string featherColor, double flightSpeed)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.animalClass = animalClass;
                this.featherColor = featherColor;
                this.flightSpeed = flightSpeed;
            }
        }

        public class Fish : Animal
        {
            public string scaleColor { get; set; }
            public double swimmingSpeed { get; set; }

            public Fish(string name, string animalClass,
                string scaleColor, double swimmingSpeed)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.animalClass = animalClass;
                this.scaleColor = scaleColor;
                this.swimmingSpeed = swimmingSpeed;
            }
        }
```

In this example, as all classes inherit from Animal class I could add them to an `List<Animal>`, but when I try to access the properties `furColor` and `runningSpeed` that are exclusive for Mammal class, I’ve got a error because them don’t belong to Animal class. To where these properties gone? How could I retrieve them?

Best regards,

Fabiano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it as `Mammal leopard = new Mammal();` to have access to it. Otherwise you'd need to cast `leopard` back to a mammal to retrieve them since `Animal` doesn't have the properties you require.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Class: {1}, Fur Collor: {2}, Running Speed: {3} km/h.",
        leopard.name, leopard.animalClass, ((Mammal)leopard).furColor, ((Mammal)leopard).runningSpeed);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of polymorphism ( multiple forms).

Using any language we can assert the following:

1. All Mammals are Animals - but not all Animal are Mammals;
2. All Birds are Animals - but not all Animals are Birds;
3. All Fishes are Animals - but not all Animals are Fishes;

An Abstract class can be defined as the blue print.

As per definition a blue print can only be used in order to build your concrete objects.

The same if for an Abstract class - is there to be inherited (inheritance) used to build an object  - which can be instantiated (initialised).

The Polymorphism here can be seen as the capability of assigning a derived class Mammals to the abstract class Animals - since Mammals can be Animals.

A Mammal class can have multiple forms - it can be seen as an Animal or a Mammals.

```
Animal leopard = new Mammal();
Mammal leopard = new Mammal();
```

Both instantiation are correct given the polymorphic explanation above - however `Animal leopard` will behave as per its class properties (Encapsulation) `name` and `animalClass`.

Meanwhile  `Mammal leopard` will behave as per his class properties + inheritance `name`, `animalClass`,`furColor` and `runningSpeed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the as operator at the point you want to acces the derived class's method.

```
Animal leopard = new Mammal();
Mammal mam = leopard as Animal;
if( mam != null)
{ 
    var fur = mam.furColor();
}
```

Or a more compact syntax.

```
Animal leopard = new Mammal();
var fur = (leopard as Mammal)?.furColor();
```

Using this second way, if leopard were created as a Fish, then fur would be null. This may be an issue depending on how your furColor method is intended to work in the case when a Mammal may not have fur. I.e. no fur means the furColor is null. In this case you may not be able to tell if the derived clas was a Fish or if it was a Mammal that had no fur.

Comment: This won't work. You surely mean `as Mammal`, don't you?

Comment: @Streamline thank you. That was carelessness on my part.